# Desktop Folder Redirection and Shortcuts

Tags: desktop, folder-redirection, shares

I have a Server 2008 with a load of group policies from a previous support contractor.

One in particular is confusing me. Desktop folder redirection is enabled and pointing at a network share but all of the shortcuts are broken white icons.

We have another network share where all of our software is installed.

The shortcuts in the desktop share are pointing to `c:\program files\office` etc

Shouldn't they be pointing to `\\server\software\office`

Thanks

Comment: How can anyone possibly answer a question like this about **your** environment?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.  The folder redirection for the desktop copies the shortcuts to a network folder, but should change the internal paths.  I'd expect to see Office still installed in \program files\Microsoft Office...  Can you verify that?

Answer (score 1):

Folder Redirection doesn't change the destination of shortcuts. Rather, it changes the paths for certain "well known folders" ("My Documents", "Desktop", "Application Data", etc-- known as "User Shell FolderS") in the registry and moves around the files in these folders to reflect their new path. It doesn't make changes to the files being redirected-- it just moves them and changes the path to the redirected folder in the registry. When an application queries Windows for the path to the user's "My Documents" folder and the folder is redirected the application receives the redirected path.

With that in mind, it would be highly irregular for Microsoft Office to be installed in a shared folder on a server computer. I don't believe that's been a "supported" configuration since Office 97.

Comment: Ok so perhaps I should rephrase my question. How would I go about giving all of my users in the staff group one set of desktop items and the students group another set?